# Use Edge Chromium as Webview in Cordova Windows Universal App

Tags: windows, cordova, webview

Is it possible to use the new Edge Chromium (Webview2) in a cordova windows universal app?

Comment: Maybe its getting close (https://windowsreport.com/microsoft-edge-webview-2/)

Answer (score 2):

No. Not at the moment. Microsoft current doesn't provide Webview2 for UWP. So even though you have the Edge Chromium, your UWP app will work using the old version of Edge browser using webview. Microsoft plans for support in the future but has not come as of today.

[Check this out](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2019/06/18/building-hybrid-applications-with-the-webview2-developer-preview/)